# Opencart: Adding customer first name to order email

Tags: php, email, opencart

I am trying to amend the order.tpl for OpenCart in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order.tpl` so the email says something like:

```
Hello (firstname)!

Welcome to my store... etc.
```

I believe it has something to do with:

```
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_greeting; ?></p>
```

But I am guessing I would need to load some new PHP above the `$text_greeting`.
I am not familiar with php unfortunately.

Hoping someone can help me out.

---

Further info:

It seems like I need to load a new value from the database i.e. load 'firstname' into catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order.tpl which is currently in the database.

I am really out of my depth with php, so I would be grateful for anyone with knowledge of opencart and php to help me out here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this should be a clean solution that gets You directly where You need:

**1. edit the `catalog/language/<YOUR_LANGUAGE>/mail/order.php`** and before the line (in English):

```
$_['text_new_greeting']         = 'Thank you for your interest in %s products. Your order has been received and will be processed once payment has been confirmed.';
```

add this one

```
$_['text_title']                = 'Hello %s,';
```

**2. open up `catalog/model/checkout/order.php`** - search for method `confirm()` and then find the line

```
$template->data['text_greeting'] = sprintf($language->get('text_new_greeting'), html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

and before it add this one:

```
$template->data['text_title'] = sprintf($language->get('text_titler'), html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_firstname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

I just want to mention that this should be done twice - once for HTML template part and once for TEXT template part (scroll down a little bit for TEXT tpl part).

**3. open `catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/mail/order.tpl`** and find the line:

```
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_greeting; ?></p>
```

and before it add this one:

```
<p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_title; ?></p>
```

Now You should be done.